# Google App Script: Trigger for email and using CC

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, carbon-copy

I have a Google Spreadsheet which once populated from a form, I want the user to be emailed back the contents of the form.

Currently it emails the editors of the form but I want to include the person that actually completed the form in the first place, so the ActiveUser.

This is what I currently have which works for the current requirements but any thoughts on how to achieve this additional functionality?

```
function sendFormByEmail() {
// set Form Submit trigger from Resources above
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssName = ss.getName();
var editors = ss.getEditors().join(",");
var owner = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
var subject = "SBS Helpline Enquiry " + ss.getSheetValues(ss.getLastRow(),2,1,1) + "            Requires Action";
<BR/>
// 'to' below will be the recipients of the emailed form responses
// can be to = any one of ( editors , owner , custom , test) no quotes
// both sides of the = should be the same color (not including 'var')
var to = ss.getEditors()// AFTER TESTING: change to either editors , owner , custom
// no quotes in above
var responses=ss.getActiveSheet();
var width=responses.getLastColumn();
var headers=responses.getRange(1,1,1,width ).getValues()[0];
var data=responses.getRange(responses.getLastRow(),1,1,width ).getValues()[0];
var message="PLEASE FORWARD THIS ENQUIRY TO THE RELEVANT CONTACTS" + "\n\n";
for(var i=0;i<width;i++){message+=headers[i] + ' = '+ data[i] + "\n\n";};
MailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,message); 
};
```

This was resolved, used

```
to=ss.getSheetValues(ss.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(), 8, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Here's one of the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial?hl=en#section1) about sending an email confirmation. You should be able to modify that and use here?

Comment: Still had no joy, looked and tried lots of different options. The email address is in column 8 of the last active row but I can't get it to pick that up and then include in the to line?

Comment: You could use .getLastRow to get the value from the last row. Something like '  to=ss.getSheetValues(ss.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(), 8, 1, 1);' should work. Do you get any specific error with this one?

Comment: Thank you @Chris - that sorted it

Answer (score 0):

There is formEmailer https://sites.google.com/site/formemailer/ 
It will do what you want without the need to write code.